# How to get the last redirected page via the requested page with HTTP request or Guzzle client in PHP

Tags: php, httprequest, guzzle

I am working on a PHP Laravel project. I am sort of developing a scraper or crawler. In my code, I need to make an HTTP request to a page that is redirecting to another page. For example, I make an HTTP request to https://example.com/page-1. But the page itself is redirecting to https://example.com/page-2. Literally, the last page landed is https://example.com/page-2 even though the request was made to https://example.com/page-1. Is it possible to get the last page landed using Guzzle or any other HTTP client in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Guzzle has follow redirect enabled by default (`http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#redirects`).
The reason why you do not get the last page contents is probably because that page uses JS or meta redirect. 
In this case i think you will need to parse that first page for redirect url.

Comment: Hi I am looking at it and it seems not to be working. Also, it is not returning the URL the last page landed. Is it possible to retrieve it?